# Weird Black Border in CSS

Tags: html, css, border, gradient, linear-gradients

I've created a box with a fade-background. Because of this, I get a weird black border on the right side and I don't know how to fix this.
(The missing left border's on purpose.)

```
#fadebox
{
    width: 300px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #055100, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 0 1 0 round;
}
```

[Weird_Black_Border_Image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Ub0.png)

Comment: Try and give the div a height (or just a text), then you should see the problem

Comment: Could you use the snippet tool to construct an example we can see? It would really help us to find the issue. Its the one with this symbol "<>" when editing your question

Comment: There is an image showing my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One naive implementation is just by specifying border-right : 0;
So if you want just a solution and not why exactly it happened go ahead and use the following:

```
#fadebox
{
    width: 300px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #055100, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 0 1 0 round;
    border-right: 0;
}
```

It's most likely happening because of to right background-image and border-image combining together but border-right: 0 should solve it.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I tried it with "none", with "0px" but not with 0... Anyway, now it works, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help, we're all in the same boat after all! Tick your question as answered so that it can help someone else as well in the future.